# Fully remove unused field references (e.g. logging) with Proguard

Tags: java, logging, proguard

I'm trying to remove logging from my app. Here's a very simple, **isolated**, but full example:

#### Java files (default package, all in same file, located in `src/source.java`)

```
class Logger {
    public void log() {
        new Exception().printStackTrace();
    }
}
class LoggerFactory {
    public static Logger createLogger() {
        return new Logger();
    }
}
class Normal {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.createLogger();
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Normal main");
        LOG.log();
    }
}
```

#### Proguard configuration (`config.pro`)

```
-injars src/test.jar
-outjars opt/test.jar
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-dontobfuscate
-optimizationpasses 3

# keep entry points
-keep class ** { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }
# usual approach to removing logging
-assumenosideeffects class Logger { void log(); }
# attempted solution for my problem:
-assumenosideeffects class LoggerFactory { Logger createLogger(); }
-assumenosideeffects class Normal { Logger LOG; }
```

#### Build script

```
set PATH=%JAVA7_HOME%\bin;.\proguard5.2.1\bin\;P:\tools\decompile\jad-1.5.8g-win\

cd src
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 *.java
jar cfM test.jar *.class
java -cp test.jar Normal

cd ..
call proguard @config.pro -verbose
java -cp test.jar Normal

cd opt
jar xf test.jar
jad -dead -noconv -nocast -noclass -v -a -o -s java *.class
```

#### Output (simplified)

```
$java -cp src/test.jar Normal
Normal main
java.lang.Exception
        at Logger.log(source.java:3)
        at Normal.main(source.java:15)

$proguard @config.pro -verbose
ProGuard, version 4.7
... last optimizing pass prints 0 changes

$java -cp opt/test.jar Normal
Normal main
```

#### Problem

As you can see above the output is as expected, there's no output from the `log()` calls. However, when I took a closer look on the resulting `.jar` file, both `Logger` and `LoggerFactory` exists and they're even used:

```
class Normal {
    public static transient void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Normal main");
        //    0    0:getstatic       #8   <Field PrintStream System.out>
        //    1    3:ldc1            #1   <String "Normal main">
        //    2    5:invokevirtual   #10  <Method void PrintStream.println(String)>
        Logger _tmp = LOG;
        //    3    8:getstatic       #7   <Field Logger LOG>
        //    4   11:pop             
        //    5   12:return          
    }

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.createLogger();
    static {
        //    0    0:invokestatic    #9   <Method Logger LoggerFactory.createLogger()>
        //    1    3:putstatic       #7   <Field Logger LOG>
        //*   2    6:return          
    }
}
```

If I see it correctly the root cause is these two instructions:

```
        //    3    8:getstatic       #7   <Field Logger LOG>
        //    4   11:pop
```

if I could get rid of those then the optimization would notice the unused `LOG` field and hopefully get rid of the initializer fully. And since there would be no uses of those logger classes, they would be shrinked.

**What am I missing? Is this not possible or am I just using the wrong options. If so what options do I need to make it happen?**

Comment: This question was an attempt to reproduce a problem I had, and it failed, because all I needed is to upgrade ProGuard. After another day of trying I came up with this repro and bug report for the latest version: https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/621/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of ProGuard.
Try using version 5.2.1 (available [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/downloads.html)), and you should get the expected result.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the difference. I was using 5.2.1.

Comment: Which part of `set PATH=...;.\proguard5.2.1\bin\ ` suggest that it's an outdated version? I just downloaded the ZIP explicitly for the minimal repro from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/5.2/

Comment: That is in your output: ProGuard, version 4.7

Comment: Aaaah, man. That ZIP I downloaded is not portable. The `proguard.bat` reads an environment variable, which is set to the Android SDK's proguard on my system. Calling `set PROGUARD_HOME=` before the proguard invocation helped.

Comment: It works on this toy example, but not on production code. It looks like this `LoggerFactory` was too simple. There are still many `getstatic LOG; pop;` sequences all over when an inner class is involved, but only then. I'll try to write a better repro.

Comment: Would be great if you can come up with a minimal sample that illustrates the problem and ask it in another question.

Answer (score 1):

You've been tricked by subtle nuances of ProGuard's keep options!

The rules you are looking for should be these:

```
# keep entry points
-keepclasseswithmembers class ** {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# usual approach to removing logging
-assumenosideeffects class Logger { void log(); }

# careful with this one, it's potentially very dangerous
# but in this case it seems necessary (perfect solution probably only with Dexguard)
-assumenosideeffects class Logger { <init>(); }
```

You have to be careful with this rule:

```
-keep class ** {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

It actually keeps all classes (even when they are empty). And besides that it keeps their main methods (if there are any). I replaced it with a rule that keeps only a class having the `main(String[])` method (and it keeps the method too).

Usage of correct `-assumenosideeffects` is a bit complicated. It's actually necessary to omit `Logger`'s constructor instead of `LoggerFactory.createLogger()`. This is probably due to order of applied optimizations and `createLogger()` method seems to be optimized out and replaced by `new Logger()` which would be kept.

When you are not sure what's the problem with your options, it good to use

```
-whyareyoukeeping class_specification
```

option. It will try to point you to what's keeping the class.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I used version 5.2.1 of ProGuard.

Comment: Huh, indeed. Thank you for the detailed answer! Changing to `keepclasseswithmembers` let Proguard inline the method. I saw the default ctors and was wondering what's up there, but didn't connect the dots. **The problem still stands though, `class Logger` is kept and `LOG` is still there.**

Comment: By the way, `-whyareyoukeeping` is pretty useless with optimizations, because it only runs before the first pass. Proguard output actually shows that `LoggerFactory` is being kept, but then after one pass the class count goes down and it is actually removed. So it is **not** being kept. I'm expecting the same to happen with `Logger` and `LOG` field.

Comment: You should not use -assumenosideeffects with constructors like suggested in this answer (-assumenosideeffects class Logger { <init>(); }). This will eventually lead for unwanted effect as also the default constructor of the Object class might get removed.

Comment: Well, I checked it and I see only class `Normal` in the output, nothing else (using the 3 rules and `-optimizationpasses 3`).

Comment: @T.Neidhart there can be no unwanted sideeffects if the Logger ctor is messed up, because I explicitly want **any** traces of the Logger class fully gone from the resulting jar! He did not use `class ** { <init>(); }` so I don't think it would affect anything extending `Object`.

Comment: The assumenosideeffects option is very powerful but also very dangerous. The way ProGuard works in this respect is to mark also all methods in super-classes of the specified classes, thus in case of constructors will finally also mark Object(). This is very wrong and will lead to undefined behavior and should never be done.

Comment: btw. with Dexguard, the commercial variant or ProGuard, you can use an additional option -assumenoexternalsideeffect that allows to mark also constructors in a safe way, to further improve removal of logging calls.

Comment: Uff, ok, I have no idea about these details.